# Circuit to drive 3 LEDs that flicker independently

Tags: led, low-power

My basic requirement is that I need 3 higher-powered LEDs that flicker (like those little battery-operated candles you can get), powered from one power supply. The three LEDs should flicker independently.

One way that I know of doing this, is by wiring a "flickering LED" (a.k.a. "candle flicker LED") before the higher-powered LED - similar to [this approach](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/does-this-led-sound-funny-to-you/).

[image: schematic diagram]

<sub>Image source: [Evil Mad Scientist - Does this LED sound funny to you?](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/does-this-led-sound-funny-to-you/)</sub>

The issue with the referenced article is that it seems rather hacky (i.e. the bundled collection of resistors, etc) and that I need 3 LEDs in total, flickering independently.

Given this, I was wondering if someone might be able to help advise exactly what I need to wire where, and what I need to get?

[This is the type of higher-powered LEDs](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/led-wired-bolts/little-dot-smd-led-accent-light/639/1926/) that I'm looking at getting, and [this](https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/constant-voltage-power-supplies/12v-dc-cps-series-power-supply/4273/9569/) (or something similar) is the 12V power pack I was looking at getting (I would consider driving this off a battery pack, but I want it to be on a timer and I haven't found any good low voltage timing solutions). I also want to be able to add a dimmer, just in case they end up being too bright, etc.

Again, I believe this is fairly basic and there may even be a better way of doing this than using the hack referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea behind the article is sound enough- don’t try to develop the flicker algorithm but simply amplify the current from the off-the-shelf (sort of) LED. Without some characterization of current vs light output of the LED it’s difficult to judge what circuit would be appropriate. You could measure that with a digital oscilloscope and a bit of circuitry. It would be easy to simply build the suggested circuit and see if it has any defects in the appearance.

An alternative would be to develop (or copy) a flicker algorithm and implement it in a microcontroller, using PWM and a MOSFET to drive the LEDs. Many years ago, I did that with an 8-pin PIC microcontroller and it worked out okay, but not especially convincing. I also mixed colours to get blue and orange flame-like hues.

Comment: Ya, given my current knowledge in the area, I'd definitely like to go with an off the shelf version. As for the current vs. output, again my knowledge is rather limited. I know enough to wire led strips and to make sure that i size a power supply appropriately, but throwing in diodes that need resistors, etc is beyond my "current" knowledge. I was really hoping someone would be able to point me to exactly which resistors I need and where to make this work and then I could figure out the why's of how it works later.